# How to create area graph in android

Tags: android, graph, pie-chart

Hi i wanted to create area graph chart and pie chart in android without using any 3rd party library, from the scratch, can you please give me some reference how to draw it from the scratch?

Answer (score 0):

see method descriptions in this class for drawing and filling primitives (rectabgles, polylines, arcs, etc) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html